# Wordpress, linux, server foldername

Tags: linux, directory, delete-file

I have a problem with deleting or even accessing folders on linux server.

The folders are located in wp-content of wordpress.

The problem is I can't open server folder listing in winscp because the folders have weird names.

Example names:

If I execute `ls -l` I can see I have required permissions and names like : 
 ???               < - folder name example
??

I tried openning in filezilla which successfully connects to wp-content folder(winscp can't even do that) , but after entering the wp-content I can't open above mentioned folders or even rename them .

I tried ssh-ing into linux server but I can't manage to cd into above folders because it says that it can't find the file/directory.

what are the options for deleting files with special characters?

Tried using single quotes and backlashes, but when clicking tab nothing happens...

is it possible to delete all folders except the required ones - then I could name which ones to leave and delete all others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use double quotation marks around the name of the file and asterisk wildcard as far as I know (asterisk means zero or more characters).

Have you tried this:

*rm -rf -- *" ###  "* 

where ### are the special characters

This website might be helpful:
https://www.computerhope.com/unix/urm.htm

Good luck!